return Dash url load in apache server
I’m trying to retrieve the URL of a running Dash app hosted on an Apache server. How can I programmatically obtain the URL of the currently active Dash app? Are there any specific Python libraries or methods I should use for this purpose?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I want to get last path segment

why do you need it? Where do you need it? In browser you can use JavaScript to get document.URL or document.location.href. In Flask you could use request.url, request.path, etc. More: python - How do I get the different parts of a Flask request's url? - Stack Overflow

found with Google: Dash pages, How to get the active page URL in the page_registry dictionary - Dash Python - Plotly Community Forum
